# Feature module won't build unless layout resources exist in base module

Tags: android-instant-apps

I an instant app with around 10 feature modules and one base feature. All of the modules build correctly except for one. If I don't have the layouts for this one feature included in the base feature then the module won't build. It states that the layout resources don't exist even though they are included in the resources directories for the feature module. Has anyone seen this? What can I do to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's annoying i had to do something similar. I appended feature's name to the package of feature. Let's say my base package is `com.myapp.android`, and i have a feature named "awesome", I gave `"com.myapp.android.awesome"` as package name of that feature. Then while importing the resources I simply did, `com.myapp.android.awesome.R.id.login` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had the R imported from the curbside app base feature and not the feature module.